# EditText in ExpandableListView - Retaining focus when soft keyboard is opened

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistadapter

I have an ExpandableList with multiple groups, and each group contains a child of a different type (different layouts). I have several Activities with a similar structure, but different child views, and so I decided to write a custom Adapter for it. The adapter works well for the most part, except for a couple of problems:

1. Typing text in a child view is next to impossible. It appears like the EditText loses focus after each character is typed. I have attached a screenshot to illustrate the behaviour.
2. When groups are expanded / collapsed, after a couple of times, the text in TextViews seem to disappear, with only the first letter of the first word in each view appearing. It somehow appears as though their layout parameters are miscalculated somehow.

Here are the screenshots:
[image: EditText - Jittery typing]
[image: TextView - Layout of text in TextView]

And here is the code for my adapter:

```
public class GenericExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] groups;
    private View[] children;

    public static interface ExpandableListItemClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int groupId, int itemId);
    }

    public GenericExpandableListAdapter(Context context, String[] groups, int[] children) {
        if(groups.length != children.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Items must have the same length as groups.");
        }
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.children = new View[children.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            this.children[i] = inflater.inflate(children[i], null);
        }
    }

    public GenericExpandableListAdapter(Context context, String[] groups, View[] children) {
        if(groups.length != children.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Items must have the same length as groups.");
        }
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildTypeCount() {
        return children.length + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView != null) {
            return convertView;
        }
        return children[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupType(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView != null) {
            ((TextView) convertView).setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return convertView;
        }
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

        final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.

Add this in your Manifest file and see if it works. It did for me.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

within your activity tag so it would be something like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave up and moved on to a different approach. I did try various combinations of `windowSoftInputMode` though, but they were buggy, and often caused random crashes when expanding groups.

Comment: Oh ok great! Hope you got it!

Comment: @Jeshurun please can you post your solution here.

Comment: @Jeshurun Have you found a solution?? Could you post it?? thnx

Comment: @Bomberlatinos9:  I simply gave up on the the expandable list approach. Instead, I grouped the interface into sections and put them in a ViewPager, to strike a balance between the amount of vertical / horizontal scrolling needed. See the 3rd screen shot here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsropos.zadmin